# Name Conventions of resource file

Tags: java, conventions, resourcebundle

**Which of the name conventions you are using in your spring resource file?**

Good practice, if I'm not mistaken, use template: `<view>.<type>.<name>`, for example `order.lbl.title`.

**But:**

1. What are you doing if you have global name, for example `yes`, `no`? They are used many times in different view. Is it right every time create translate for each view?
2. If you have message for validation field, for example `email`, what is best way: create `order.form.validation.email` or create something like `validation.msg.email` and use once for all validation?

Comment: the #1 difficult problem in programming - naming things:) if it gets too frustrating, just screw it, names don't really matter that much.